# What is this token?

Tags: identify-this-game-piece

[image: Game token in the form of a coin]

I found this token underneath my table.  It's cardboard and looks well-made (it doesn't bend or fold easily, fairly thick).  I have no idea where it came from or what it belongs to, but it probably belongs to a board game I played at some point or other.  Does anyone know what it is or where it's from?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It appears to be from the game [Sheriff of Nottingham](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/157969/sheriff-nottingham)

[image]

Comment: That's the one!  Found a clearer image on Google.  Interesting, I have played that game once before at my apartment, but only once, and I do not own it.  Now I have to remember who it was I played it with XD

Comment: I hope you can track down the copy it came from! I've got the game (that's how I recognised it), but I'm no good at bluffing games...